# priority defaults value or another function? ( overload )

Tags: c#, .net, function

why this return 5,I'm curious about this the normal function have higher priority over with a default parameter one. can some body explain me this. thanks in advance

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Console.WriteLine(add());

        Console.ReadLine();
}



public static int add(int x=4,int y=5)
{
        return x+y;
}

public static int add()
{

        return 5;

}
```

Comment: It doesn't return 5, it returns 8.  Did you misspeak?

Comment: @antisanity - It returns 8 because the value of 3 is being passed as the first parameter of the method.  Therefore the parameter `x` gets the value of 3, and the second parameter is left with the default value of 5.

Comment: @antisanity something changed. He called `add(3)` before.

Comment: every one are right I've changed the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can only be answered by looking at the C# language specification. Section 7.5.3.2 says that when determining a "Better" function member, if the optional arguments are not needed, you throw them out:

> Optional parameters with no corresponding arguments are removed from
>   the parameter list

That effectively makes the two functions equivalent. It then has the following tie-breaker rule for when two functions are equivalent:

> Otherwise if all parameters of MP have a corresponding argument
>   whereas default arguments need to be substituted for at least one
>   optional parameter in MQ then MP is better than MQ.

That would mean that the one without the default arguments would be the one called - just as you're seeing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, methods are either overloaded or they use default parameters.  It's a design choice, though I find myself writing overloaded methods instead of default parameterized ones.

In this case, the compiler has to make a decision about which method to call, and the method without any parameters is given priority.

Answer (score 0):

It returns 5 because you called a method `add()` with no parameters.  How should the compiler know which one you want based on the one with default parameters?  It has to pick one.  That's the way it was designed to work.

If you want to read more about optional arguments I suggest you read Eric Lippert's series on it.  You can start [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one.aspx).